# svn export from HEAD

Tags: svn

I have been doing an svn export from a working copy I have, but I am unsure of how to do a svn export from my latest revision in the repository.

This is what I use now:

`svn export /path/to/working/dir` which exports the dir folder to the current directory I am in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same, just use its URL

```
svn export http://URL
```

It will export to your current directory. In case you want different directory use the following form

```
svn export http://URL different_directory
```

You can get more info from `svn help export`

> $ svn help export
>
> export: Create an unversioned copy of a tree.
>   usage:
>   1. export [-r REV] URL[@PEGREV] [PATH]
>   2. export [-r REV] PATH1[@PEGREV] [PATH2]
>
> 1. Exports a clean directory tree from the repository specified by
>       URL, at revision REV if it is given, otherwise at HEAD, into
>       PATH. If PATH is omitted, the last component of the URL is used
>       for the local directory name.
> 2. Exports a clean directory tree from the working copy specified by
>       PATH1, at revision REV if it is given, otherwise at WORKING, into
>       PATH2.  If PATH2 is omitted, the last component of the PATH1 is used
>       for the local directory name. If REV is not specified, all local
>       changes will be preserved.  Files not under version control will
>       not be copied.